# How to write text over image with coordinates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a image with and i want display some text over image when i clicked 1 point in image, my problem is text don't display in mouse point, it display below mouse.
It is my code: 
Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#imgEx").click(function(e) {
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
            var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);
            //alert("X: " + relativeX + ' -' + " Y: " + relativeY);
            var text = document.getElementById('textEx');
            text.textContent = "X: " + relativeX + ' -' + " Y: " + relativeY;
            text.style.left = relativeX + "px";
            text.style.top = relativeY - 30 + "px"; // minus one range you want display text in image ( my number is 30 to display in mouse point)
        });

    });

</script>
```

and my form:

```
<form method="POST">
    <div class="image">
        <img id="imgEx" type="image" alt="image" src="./src/assets/cat.jpg" style="width:700px; height:600px" >
        <h2 id="textEx"></h2>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I think no need to calculate the offset height/offset width of the image. As per your HTML the text field is inside your parent div. As @Rayon suggest, Keep your parent as relative and text as absolute. and set the top/left position for the text with respect to image.

Answer (score 1):

Put `wrapper` as `relative` and `content` as `absolute`

Also use `span` element instead of `h` elements as `h` elemnt itself is associated with browser specific `style(css)`

```js
$(function() {
  $("#imgEx").click(function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
    var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);
    var text = document.getElementById('textEx');
    text.textContent = "X: " + relativeX + ' -' + " Y: " + relativeY;
    text.style.left = relativeX + "px";
    text.style.top = relativeY + "px";
  });
});
```

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
}
#textEx {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
  <div class="image">
    <img id="imgEx" type="image" alt="image" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="width:700px; height:600px">
    <span id="textEx"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, my problem is solved when i minus one range pixel to display text.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to assign **position:absolute** for #textEx

```
#textEx{
  position:absolute;
}
```